# whats causing scroll space on mobile site

Tags: css, mobile

I'm working on a site but im just wondering whats causing it to display wierdly on mobile phone. It has a side scroll when it really shouldnt. I'm wondering if its the footer thats causing it. Here is the css:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
    background:#EFDECD; //#5ee;
    text-align: center;

}
p{
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.paragraph{
font-size: 1em;
//font-family:  Charcoal, sans-serif;
}
#content {
    padding: 1em;
     padding-bottom: 7em;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.label{
margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
table{
font-size: .75em;
}

.panel.callout a:not(.button):hover{
  color: $anchor-font-color-hover;
}

.headingtext{
font-family:  Century Gothic, sans-serif;

}
.headtext{
    display:inline-block;
 //   font-size:3em;
    margin: 0 10em;
    text-align: center;
 //   font-family:"Courier New";
  //  font-weight: bold;
 //   margin-left: 6em;

}
.img2{
   // max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 25%;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
   }

.accorborder{
border: black dotted 1px;
}
h6{font-weight: bold;}
```

the link to the site to view if you could, on your mobile phone, is www.new.omegadesignla.com

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your center image `.headtext` is causing the issue. You need to adjust it, perhaps with a breakpoint depending on the devices that you are trying to target.

You can see what I'm talking about if you change it to `display: block` and give it a smaller size.

```
// Example Media Query 
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .headtext {
    // mobile-friendly styles here
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks, would there be a better more mobile friendly way to adjust it? I haven't used break points.

Comment: Media queries! Don't be scared. They're super easy.

Comment: Ha, a mobile friendly way do do it would be to use a responsive framework like skeleton or bootstrap. You can pull the em-based margin. That will get rid of the issue on mobile, but will tweak your desktop experience. If you're not willing to do some wholesale refactor and make the site truly responsive a one-of media query is your best option really.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example mq. But really a simple google search will give you plenty of solutions.